# Close voter shown, but not linked?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, closed-questions

[Flag for "not an answer" declined](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339027/6388243) seems broken. The user Michael Gaskill voted to close it, and is listed as a close voter, but it doesn't link to their profile like it should. I know that the user wasn't deleted because it still has the link to their profile in the [Close Votes review task](//meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close/12692) for the question.

Comment: @Oded see the second link in the question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2577852/michael-gaskill

Comment: Interestingly the user [isn't listed](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3SZjN.png) in the app notice

Comment: @Cai that would be 'Community'. I think Michael managed to make his close vote anonymous ... Or I hit too hard with the dupehammer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a duplicate account for him that got merged.

The details in the close notice record contain the original merged user id (now deleted), though the close vote has been updated to the current user id.

As far as I know, we do not update the details in the close notice record.